# Difficulty calling a class method in rails. Have other class methods that work fine

Tags: ruby, class-method, nomethoderror

So I am trying to write a class method to send a csv file using a mailer class. I think I have that logic all worked out and the issue I am experience is a NoMethodError. I have defined the method within my Order class (see below):

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{ id customer_name, customer_email, street_address, city, state, zip_code, number_books }
    orders = Order.where(Date.today.all_day)

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      orders.each do |order|
        csv << attributes.map { |attr| order.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am simply trying to call this method in the console to see what kind of output it gives me.

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_csv' for #<Class:0x00007fb7ef8a7560>
Did you mean?  to_s
from /Users/mymac/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

I have also tried writing any class methods that do something simple such as printing a word to the console and I get the same error. I have restarted my rails server, but I don't think I should even have to do this??

Any help is apprecitated. Having an issue with something I have done a million times without issue is extremely frustrating.

Comment: `self.method` inside a `class` cannot be called on instances of the class, they are class methods. I assume you have initialised an instance of `Order` Remove `self` and you should be able to call the method.

Comment: I am calling this method in my terminal exactly as follows: "Order.to_csv". I am getting the same error with instance methods as well. I just tried to create an instance method and call it on an individual instance of an Order (Order.first) and got the same error.

Comment: I am restarting my console and this also does not help.

Comment: Try testing it using rspec/minitest. Maybe you'll get a more meaningful error

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: Within Rails the auto-loader should take care of things like this, but if it ever gets confused the Spring pre-loader might be at fault, so `spring stop` can help reset that.

Comment: HOW ANNOYING. THAT WORKED!!! THANKS! Damn spring......

Comment: if you post that as an answer tadman, I will give it a green check mark.

Comment: ALWAYS disable spring. spring is NEVER worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails normally reloads anything in `app/` and `config/routes.rb` when they're changed but there are circumstances under which the class doesn't properly reload and a cached version of the old version is stuck. This is most often caused by [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) which tries to keep up-to-date but can slip out of sync on occasion.

The usual fix is:

```
spring stop
```

You can also disable it if it's causing a lot of hassles for you. The Rails start-up time might be slower, but it might not be an issue for you.